# Math regex expression

Tags: regex, math

I need a regex expression to split math expression, like:

```
-1*x+2*y
```

to the: `-1*x` and `2*y`

I can't just split that string basing in the `+` and `-` (because there can be negative numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split on `+` or `-` which is preceded by a letter, digit and potentially other elements that are acceptable in your expressions (parenthesis for example). You can use [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to accomplish this.

For example in python you can do it like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9)])[+-]', '-a+10*x-2*y+(-2)-b')
['-a', '10*x', '2*y', '(-2)', 'b']
```

This splits on every `+` or `-` not preceded by a small or capital letter or a digit or a closing parenthesis. You may need to tweak this depending on your exact specification of what constitutes a "math expression".

This or similar regular expression should work in other regexp engines.

Answer (score 2):

Math expressions are a classic application for parsers.

Regexes are not really powerful enough to do the job right.  Even if you can abuse advanced features in your regex library to force-fit a solution, the result may be kind of hairy as a consequence.

Answer (score 0):

What if you always split on `+` and only split on `-` if it's not at the beginning of an expression or following a '+' (and spaces)?